# Sorting a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm working with entity framework database and I want to populate my dropdownlist from a table but in right order.

Right now i'm using the code:

```
var databaseList = from p in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
                   where p.skill_type == "Database"
                   select new EmployeeTechnicalSkillInfo
                       {
                           TechnicalSkillId = p.technical_skill_id,
                           SkillType = p.skill_type,
                           SkillName = p.skill_name
                       };

        List<object> sDataValue = new List<object>();
        sDataValue.Add("- Select -");
        sDataValue.Remove("Other");

        foreach (var vData in databaseList)
        {
            sDataValue.Add(vData.SkillName);
        }

        sDataValue.Add("Other");

        DropDownListDB.DataSource = sDataValue.ToArray();
        DropDownListDB.DataBind();
```

This is the **Solution**

```
    var databaseList = from p in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
           where p.skill_type == "Database"
           orderby p.skill_name != "Other" descending, p.skill_name
           select new EmployeeTechnicalSkillInfo
               {
                   TechnicalSkillId = p.technical_skill_id,
                   SkillType = p.skill_type,
                   SkillName = p.skill_name
               };
```

Comment: Are Select and Other values from database or you add them additionally?

Comment: Are those values ("-Select-" and "Other") present in the database?

Comment: I'm not a linq expert but can't you apply a order by in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try play with orderby with boolean value

```
orderby p.skill_name != "Other" descending, p.skill_name
```

In your code =>

```
var databaseList = from p in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
               where p.skill_type == "Database"
               orderby p.skill_name != "Other" descending, p.skill_name
               select new EmployeeTechnicalSkillInfo
                   {
                       TechnicalSkillId = p.technical_skill_id,
                       SkillType = p.skill_type,
                       SkillName = p.skill_name
                   };

    List<object> sDataValue = new List<object>();
    sDataValue.Add("- Select -");

    foreach (var vData in databaseList)
    {
        sDataValue.Add(vData.SkillName);
    }

    DropDownListDB.DataSource = sDataValue.ToArray();
    DropDownListDB.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the entry `-Select-` from the list and append it as first item to your `List<object>`:

```
List<object> sDataValue = new List<object>();
sDataValue.Add("-Select-");
foreach (var vData in databaseList){}
```

would be the easiest way, I assume.

**EDIT**

then you will use `if/else`, maybe and

```
foreach (var vData in databaseList){} //fill your list
sDataValue.Add("-Other-");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

Remove `-Select-` and `Other` from databaseList like this:

```
var databaseList = from p in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS
                   where p.skill_type == "Database"
                     && p.skill_name.ToLower() !="other"
                     && p.skill_name.ToLower() !="-select-"

                   select new EmployeeTechnicalSkillInfo
                       {
                           TechnicalSkillId = p.technical_skill_id,
                           SkillType = p.skill_type,
                           SkillName = p.skill_name
                       };
```

and then do this:

```
DropDownListDB.DataSource = sDataValue.ToArray().OrderBy(s=>s);
DropDownListDB.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");
DropDownListDB.Items.Add("Other");
```

if you must bring -Select- and Other field from database, binding them to the DropDownList and then removing them and again inserting them at appropriate location is little expensive.

You simply don't pick those two rows from the database. it will be more efficient.

Comment: then find other from the database and remove it from your list. and do this code. it will be more effecient

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "section id" to your database: 0 for "-Select-", 2 for "Other", 1 for the rest. Then sort on 1) section ID, 2) name.

But it would be best not to store that "-Select-" at all (it doesn't represent a valid value) and add it in the correct spot after the databind.

Comment: Agreed.  Having -Select- in the database doesn't make much sense. I'd restructure the approach, rather than shoe-horn a solution around it.